# Passing clicks events from floating app to covered app

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a floating app which works perfectly.

I am using OnTouchListener to catch events since I need to use the GestureDetector for swipes etc.
My only problem is that sometimes I wish to ignore certain events on the view.
In this case the view is invisible but not "gone" because I need it to accept certain gestures but not others.
I can't seem to be able to do that.
Returning false from "onTouch" simply doesn't work.

I checked that by experiment by disabling the GestureDetector and simply always returning false just to see what would happen. Result was nothing going through.

Is it even possible to pass a click through to a covered app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security reasons it's not possible to record and pass a click below (essentially allows building a keylogger).

Best you can do is have your floating window small enough to start the touch but not cover too much of the screen below.

Comment: You have a fiendish mind. But makes a lot of sense. The view is smallish but still covers a bit too much. Guess I can make it a little smaller. Maybe make it an option for the user.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might consider displaying two floating views at once: small one that consumes touch, and untouchable larger one to display information.

Comment: That won't work in my case. The point is that I want the view to be clickable even when the user can't actually see it. Seems my only solution is changing the size. Definitely doable but not perfect. Also, allowing the user to re-locate the view will help. That's a planned feature anyway.